# how to open facebook specific profile in iphone using graph api?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

okay...
I am implementing facebook in iphone..

In that i want to open a specific profile in the facebook..

do anyone know how can i do it using graph api??

Answer (score 0):

It's simple trick to get the profile of a specific person. Instead of passing me/feed pass the specific person ID as eg. 1234567/feed you will get his profile details

Comment: thanks ... but I want that when I press the button...I want to see the specific user's profile in the dialogue box..do u know how to do this?